# Wazuh ElasticSearch Bad Request "_license"

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, wazuh

`talk to server... ERROR Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: could not connect to a compatible version of Elasticsearch: 400 Bad Request: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_index_name_exception","reason":"Invalid index name [_license], must not start with '_'.","index":"_license","index_uuid":"_na_"}],"type":"invalid_index_name_exception","reason":"Invalid index name [_license], must not start with '_'.","index":"_license","index_uuid":"_na_"},"status":400}`

I'm encountering the error mentioned above when I run the 'filebeat test output' command on my Wazuh master node. I have no idea where the error is coming from.

Wazuh Indexer version : 4.5.0-1
Filebeat version : 7.17.12
Elasticsearch version in the Wazuh Indexer: 7.10.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Filebeat 7.10.2 because 7.17.12 is not compatible with ES 7.10.2 as it will make API calls (to check the license) that 7.10.2 does not understand.